# Blank values in DB from async function with multiple awaits

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a model as so

```
public class Action () 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual User CompletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And an async function as so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MarkActionCompleted(int id) 
{        
    using(MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext()) 
    {
        UserManager userManager = new UserManager(new UserStore(db));
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var action = await db.Actions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

        if (action == null)
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }

        action.Completed = true;
        action.CompletedOn = DateTime.Now;
        action.CompletedBy = user;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

I've been noticing, by looking at all the entries on my DB that about 2% (441/21547) of records are marked completed but both the CompletedBy and CompletedOn are null. I've been trying to wrap my head around how this can be. This is the only function that modifies this table.

So my question is, Am i using async/await incorrectly? Is it possible that `SaveChangesAsync` is being called before the user is retrieved? Or is perhaps an issue with Context? Should I be using `ConfigureAwait(false)` somewhere?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's not related to that piece of code. Is the number of those actions increasing over time?

Comment: Are are there multiple clients updating the database at the same time? If yes, then your changes may be overwritten by another client within a very short span of time..

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It's definitely still happening, another record this morning. Seems to happen once every day or so. I'm pretty perplexed, it's the only code that modifies these records. I thought perhaps it might have to do with the user timing out? However that doesn't explain the blank date.

Comment: @Sunil Yes ~100 users at a time, how would your scenario work though, wouldn't it just replace the information with the other user?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Sorry I didn't answer your quesiton correctly.. No, it's usually only 1 time a day every day or so. Maybe twice in a day from time to time.

Comment: If 2 users are updating the same row in a table then second user will over write the saved values of first user. In your case, a row in the Actions table could be getting updated by 2 users within a few seconds apart.

Comment: @Sunil I understand but then the values wouldn't be blank would they? It would be which ever call resolves last, right?

Comment: @GregB unless the user modifying the rows sets them back to null